# Inconsistent behaviour of AES encryption

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I have integrated cryptojs in my project where I am using this function to encrypt the message

```
let encMsg: string = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, aesKey, {iv: aesIv}).toString()
```

It is working and returns base64 in encMsg however it sometimes returns the hex value encMsg instead of base64. I am not sure why it is happening and how to control it to return base64 only.

Please help.

Comment: What does *sometimes* mean: is it always Base64 encoded for certain input data and always hex encoded for others? Then post example data that leads to a hex encoded ciphertext. Or is it sometimes Base64, sometimes hex encoded for the same input data? The latter might be a special problem of your environment: With what frequency is the data hex encoded in this case? Check if for hex encoded ciphertexts really the posted code is executed. Also, check your CryptoJS library (original or derivative library, version etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` function should always return an object which encapsulates the ciphertext. If you call `.toString()` directly on this object without any cipher encoding specified, it defaults to a `CipherParams` formatter that turns this object into a string; this may not always result in the the base64 encoding of the ciphertext.

You can enforce base64 output by using the `.toString()` function of the `CryptoJS.enc.Base64` object on the ciphertext attribute of the encrypt function's result like so:

```
let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, aesKey, {iv: aesIv});
let encMsg = encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

With this, `encrypted` is a `CipherParams` object. It contains several attributes including ciphertext which is a `WordArray` object. By using `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.toString(encrypted.ciphertext)`, you're converting the `WordArray` object to a base64-encoded string.

This should always give you a base64 string representing the ciphertext.

Comment: In your code example you don't use `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.toString()` explicitly. Do you mean to say that this will be used internally by `CipherParams#toString(encoder)`? Both methods will probably work, but I guess that this can be cleared up a bit further in the answer (PS. deleted my answer, you've worded it better).

Comment: Yes, you're correct. When you call `encrypted.toString()`, it implicitly uses `CryptoJS.format.OpenSSL.stringify(encrypted)`, which internally uses `CryptoJS.enc.Base64` to turn the ciphertext into a base64 string.

The `CryptoJS.format.OpenSSL` format outputs a base64-encoded string which represents the salted ciphertext in OpenSSL's format. This format is a Base64 encoded string with a header that includes the salt.

Comment: Although you describe the CryptoJS implementation correctly, this does not explain the user's problem. `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(...).toString()` should (by default) return a Base64 encoding, not *sporadically* a hex encoding. `encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)` may be a workaround, but the OP is probably well advised to identify the real problem.

Comment: The answer is  likely ChatGPT like your other answers today